# Merge conditional formatting rules of two different cells in a single cell

Tags: conditional-formatting

I have a cell (say A1) whose value ranges between 0 and 1.
Then I have other two other cells (say B1 and B2), each one with a specific conditional formatting rule based on the value in A1.

What I want to do is to copy both the rules to a SINGLE cell (say C3).
That is, C3 should use the same rule of B1 *and* the same rule of B2.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and you are using Microsoft Excel; try the following:

1. Select both/all cells that have the formatting that you want to merge using CTRL+Left-click or a range select.
2. On the **Home** ribbon control at the top, click the **Conditional Formatting** button and from the drop-down click **Manage Rules**.
3. From the dialog on screen select the rules you want and in the **Applies To** column, select the cell ranges that the rules should be implemented for, the click **Apply**.